# Excel formula to find the second match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that finds the second match in a column:

```
A   B  
1   Thiago  
2   Joao  
3   Maria  
4   Andre  
5   Thiago  
6   Jose
```

Now I have:

```
VLOOKUP("Thiago", A:B, 1, 0)
```

It returns '1'. But it need the second match, row '5'.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`=SMALL(IF(A1:A6="Thiago",ROW(A1:A6),""),2)`

This is an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> after inserting it in a cell.